# Methods to create forms with dropdown and image upload?

Tags: javascript, android, web

My work wants to know if I could create a "form" sort of UI for our workers Android tablets that have a couple of dropdowns, a couple of text boxes, and the ability to upload pictures with it hopefully e-mailing all of the info to an address.

They kept talking about an "app" but I was thinking this would be easier just as a web page with these features.  My problem is I am not sure where to start.  If someone could give me some tips to get ie What language to use, Should I go web app or android app / anything else you would add.

Comment: Why don't you try hybrid mobile development ? I will require HTML5,Javascript,CSS

Comment: ok I know a bit of each of those! What would I search for to find some tutorials on this subject?

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides see this link of Cordova I think It will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you know Java you will at home with Android development, and Android Studio is a good tool for creating your apps, with a very good layout editor. With marginal research you could implement the form style app that you describe.

If you prefer C++ over Java, you can also look into [Qt](http://www.qt.io/) for Android development. Really discovering the languages for android development is a matter of using your favorite search engine.

Some pros of developing an app over a web form might be

- Solid integration with the cameras of the tablets, as you describe image upload
- Integration with Email apps
- The final product is arguably easier to use

The only con I can think of is that it seems like you have to do some learning first, which might actually not be a con at all.

Comment: yea I think it would be good to learn even if it takes me a bit.  thank you, for the response!